# How to pass query and receive result form controller to view using widget('yiiwheels.widgets.typeahead.WhTypeAhead') .

Tags: yii

I'm try to create Yii Autocomplete widget from Database.
**controller.php** i need view.php code.

```
            public function actionGetPatient() {
            $res =array();
            if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $sql ="SELECT Name FROM tbl_patients WHERE Name LIKE :lName";
            $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
            $command->bindValue(":lName", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $res =$command->queryColumn();
            echo CJSON::encode($res);
            Yii::app()->end(); 
            }

            **view.php** 
            <?php
            //i need this code
            ?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use This Link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/162/a-simple-action-for-cjuiautocomplete/

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
      'attribute'=>'my_name',
        'model'=>$model,
        'sourceUrl'=>array('my/aclist'),
        'name'=>'my_input_name',
        'options'=>array(
          'minLength'=>'3',
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
          'size'=>45,
          'maxlength'=>45,
        ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do like this..

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('yiiwheels.widgets.typeahead.WhTypeAhead', array(
        'id' => 'anID',
        'name' => 'aName',
        'htmlOptions' => array('placeholder' => 'A Place Holder'),
        'pluginOptions' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'a name',
                'remote'=> 'http://yourdomain.com/Controller/action?param1=value1&param2=%QUERY',
            ))
    ));
    ?>
```

**NOTE:** `%QUERY` will pass your input

You can get the typeahead suggessions from the database using "`remote`".

http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/